# how to read the string of a particular <html> tag in android

Tags: android, string

I have a response in html form from the server, now I want to read the characters or say data of between particular tag, for example: font tag starting---(The data that I want to read)----font tag ending.

I have stored the string in a String Variable named "response".

How can I do this in android?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use regex Pattern.
Here's a little example, though it can be probably made more efficient and abstract:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String html = "Some text <font> here </font>, and some <font>there</font>";
    final Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("<font>(.+?)</font>");
    final Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(html);
    while (mtchr.find()) {
        final String result = html.substring(mtchr.start(), mtchr.end()).replace("<font>", "").replace("</font>", "");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
 here there
```

P.S. You probably shouldn't use this for large responses (and I think it's not adviced to use regex for html). Maybe you should use some parser (SAX for one).

Answer (score 0):

are you in a browser ? if so you can use jQuery or simply :

```
document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML;
```

Comment: I have stored the string in a String Variable named "response".